# Couldn't connect to the SFTP Server even the credentials are okay

Tags: wordpress, connection, sftp

I am developing a wordpress site, and couldn't connect to any editor for my sftp access, I use filezilla and notepad++ but can't connect, the credentials are okay, the connection is okay, my ip is not blocked from the server

it says

```
[SFTP] Connection failed : Timeout connecting to 02.34.567.891
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

what do you think is the reason or problem here?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout if you really should be using sftp and not ftp, which differa in ports, sftp 22 and ftp 21
Also you can try to connect as plain text, that is not recommendet but some servers are configured that way.
And last but not least try to connect with passive mode on fillezila, you can easily find that on your way to connecting to server or just check their documentation